# How to make VS Code Jupiter Notebook to stop code execution before a given cell?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cell, execute

How to make VS Code Jupiter Notebook to stop code execution before a given cell? I know that it is possible to start code execution from a certain cell and down by clicking the 'Execute Cell and Below' button, but then all the code will be executed to the end of the file. And it is necessary that the execution stops before the specified cell, without executing the entire code to the end. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using VS Code 1.64.2, select the chosen cell, then click on "Execute Above Cells":

[image]

Comment: This is also valid in the latest version `1.70.2`